# How to hide/remvoe unnecessary field/section in post edit section ( Dashboard )

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, themes

I am trying fix some issue in wordpress dashboard. if you see the picture you will find that there are too many unnecessery field render in the post dashboard section, I have no idea how to remove this section. It would be very helpful if anyone know how to remove those section.
However i dont want to use css for hiding this section. I want to hide it by php in wordpress way :), 
Thank you .[image: reove section from wordpress dashboard]

Comment: How about simply using the [Screen Options](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/getting-to-know-wordpress/screen-options/)?

Comment: thank You, simple but really helpful trick :p